# Synonym of ess tags? Any better way to ask?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

As far as I can see, the [ess](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ess) equals the [emacs-speaks-statistics](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emacs-speaks-statistics) tag. Could you make one a synonym for the other?

Furthermore, is this the only way for me to ask that question since I don't have enough reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can create a tag synonym, and it seems pretty reasonable to me.  I'd lean toward making `ess` the master tag since that's how people who use it would probably refer to it (and thus search for it), although `emacs-speaks-statistics` is more self-informative.

Given the minimal usage of either tag, I've [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag) the `emacs-speaks-statistics` tag in the meantime.

Re: your second question: currently, you need 1250 rep to propose tag synonyms, so a meta post is one plausible way to draw attention to such a proposal until you get to the rep level (*edit*: also try suggesting it in chat, as @Faheem Mitha suggests in the comment).  You can go that route, but I'd suggest doing so sparingly.

Comment: Making a suggestion in chat is also an option. Presumably one or more mods will see it, sooner or later, and probably sooner.

Comment: I agree with creating the synonym, and making `ess` the master tag. And using the chat or the meta for these suggestions is the most reasonable way, I think. It's not like our chat is terribly crowded at the moment. :-) And even if you have 1250, I think you need a minimum amount of rep on that specific tag, which makes it even harder. And I wanted to finish this comment with a 3rd sentence starting with "And".

Comment: You forgot to make [tag:emacs-speaks-statistics] a synonym.

Comment: @Gilles: I had put a suggestion for the synonym in the system.  We now need to vote on it.  There's a hitch, though: "Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms."  We need 4 upvotes, but it turns out that there's only one user who is qualified to vote.

Comment: @Dan The reputation requirements for synonym voting make it pretty much out of reach except for a few popular tags on [so] where the synonyms have existed for a long time. As a mod, if it's clear that the synonym is warranted, just create it. If it's not clear, ask for a second opinion in chat. If it's still not clear, run a meta thread. But forget about the existence of the voting system, it isn't useful.

Comment: @Gilles: done -- finally found the menu to let me create rather than suggest.  Thanks!

Comment: Click on “see all tag synonyms »” on a tag synonym page to get to the tag synonyms dashboard where you can approve and merge suggested synonyms. If you know exactly which tags you want to merge, go to the landing page for one of the tags, click “merge” and enter the name of the other tag (if it's an existing tag, make sure you're entering the right name, because merges can't be undone).